# The changes are not getting reflected after the filters are being applied in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart

I'm writing a code to render barplot of a sentiment analysis model. I have created two filters Zone and circle. The "circle" variable is dependent on "Zone" variable. So I have written the code accordingly. I now want the changes to reflect in the barchart whenever I select some zone. Here is my code:

```
#Set locales 
rm(list = ls())
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL",locale = "English")

#Load libraries
LoadLibraries <- c("openxlsx",
                   "dplyr",
                   "tidyr",
                   "plotly",
                   "RColorBrewer",
                   "shiny")
lapply(LoadLibraries, require, character.only = TRUE)

#Read data
path = "C:/Users/R_Visual/Data/visual_data.xlsx"
input_data <- read.xlsx(path)
sentiments <- input_data[,1:10]

zone_name <- unique(input_data$Zone.Final)
circle_name <- unique(input_data$Circle.Final)

shinyApp(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Sentiment Analysis"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("Zone",
                     "Select zone",
                     choices = zone_name),
      selectizeInput("Circle",
                     "Select Circle",
                     choices = circle_name)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("barplot")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    tab <- reactive({
      
      input_data %>%
        filter(Zone.Final == input$Zone) %>%
        filter(Circle.Final == input$Circle)
    })
    
    color <- brewer.pal(10, "Set3")
    output$barplot <- renderPlot({
      tab()
      barplot(sort(colSums(input_data[,1:10])),
              main = "Sentiment Analysis",
              xlab = "Sentiments",
              ylab = "Count",
              horiz = FALSE,
              names = sentiments$name,
              col = color,
              border = FALSE,
              legend = TRUE,
              args.legend = list(bty = "n", x = "topleft", ncol = 1, cex = 0.7, y.intersp = 0.6))
    })
    
    #Selectize choice's list
    circle.choice = reactive({
      input_data %>%
        filter(Zone.Final == input$Zone) %>%
        pull(Circle.Final)
    })
    
    #Observe
    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "Circle" , choices = circle.choice())
    })
  }
)
```

I'm getting the output like this,
[image]

Now I want the changes to be reflected in the barchart. I'm very new to RShiny and can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Can't run the app without data but this is what you probably need -

```
output$barplot <- renderPlot({
      barplot(sort(colSums(tab()[,1:10])), # use tab() instead of input_data
              main = "Sentiment Analysis",
              xlab = "Sentiments",
              ylab = "Count",
              horiz = FALSE,
              names = sentiments$name, # if possible, use tab()$name here
              col = color,
              border = FALSE,
              legend = TRUE,
              args.legend = list(bty = "n", x = "topleft", ncol = 1, 
                                 cex = 0.7, y.intersp = 0.6))
    })
```